# Magento Product Custom Options Text Field Calculate Price (Width x Height)

Tags: magento

I wanted to calculate the price of the product on the basis of values entered by the user in custom options of text field. Here is the example http://www.rolgordijnstore.nl/duo-rolgordijn-basic-excl-cassette-bestellen.html

When user enter in width (Breedte in mm) and height (Hoogte in mm) it calculate the price.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways this can be achieved. Furthermore, there are subtleties, for instance you may want round prices, e.g. £4.99 rather than £5.27 for some arbitrary sized widget.

To get manageable products with round price points you can do everything in template code.

For instance, put together a configurable product that has 'small/medium/large'.

Add 'custom product options' for width and height.

In the template for that product/product type put some extra javascript to hide the configurable option box.

Add some event listeners to the width/height boxes and do some maths on them when a new value has been entered into either.

Then see if that corresponds to the area you have for 'small/medium/large'. With prototype $F update the configurable products option accordingly.

Then bubble the event, or create a new event on the update, so that the pricing is updated on the page.

On the basket page the product will show with width, height and 'size' (from the hidden configurable). This will be clear.

Naturally you can put in different sizes than 'S/M/L' - 'Size 0 -> Size 10' could be the range you choose or you could just put in the square metres into the configurable product options.

Note that you don't have to update a 'hidden configurable product' field, you could update a hidden 'custom product option'. You javascript will have to be robust if you are having lots of products so I hope your $$ prototype up() and down() skills are good.